# Can't able to call the rest api's asynchoronously

Tags: alamofire

I am new to ios threads. While calling the api in the particular screen its not giving the response until 60 seconds, In between time am calling other api's from same screens or other screens its kept loading. After 60 seconds, it will show the response.

We need to call the asynchronous api's using Alamofire. but its not working

```
private let alamofireManager : Session
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300 // seconds
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 500
alamofireManager = Session.init(configuration: configuration, serverTrustManager: .none)
alamofireManager.request("sample_api",method: .post,parameters: parameters,encoding: URLEncoding.default,headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in}
```

Comment: Define "not working" exactly. What's your issue exactly?

Comment: It gives me the response for second api once the first api call is done

Answer (score 0):

First, when getting started it's not necessary to customize anything. Especially when the values you're customizing aren't much different from the defaults.

Second, Alamofire 5.6 now ships with Swift async / await APIs, so I suggest you use those when getting started. You can investigate your network calls without tying them to specific screens until you understand the calls, how they work, and when they should be called.

Third, a 60 second delay sounds like a timeout, as 60 seconds is the default timeout wait. Is that expected? Make sure you have proper access to your server. You should also print your response so you can see what's happening and whether you got data back or an error.

Fourth, use a `Decodable` type to encapsulate your expected response, it makes interacting with various APIs much simpler. Do not use Alamofire's `responseJSON`, it's now deprecated.

So you can start your experiment by using Alamofire's default APIs.

```swift
let response1 = await AF.request("url1").serializingDecodable(Response1.self)
debugPrint(response1)
let response2 = await AF.request("url2").serializingDecodable(Response2.self)
debugPrint(response2)
```